# What is the song playing during Prop Hunt (Prop Party)?

Tags: game-music-identification, little-big-planet-2

I love the music playing during the level called Prop Hunt (Prop Party) by stormboy99. Can you tell me what those two song names are?

Comment: please add any audio source so we can listen to it. else this question will be closed soon

Comment: @Nitro.de I'd let it be. There is a tangibe song being refered to in a non-ambiguous way. It's just not a direct link, so it's just hard for anybody without the game to find it. Of coure, adding a link would always help.

Comment: @DJPirtu is was just a suggestion. I have played lbp2 months ago and can't remember the song so a link would be perfect^^ The main reason why I would prefer a link is that the level seems to be a custom one `by stormboy99` which makes it even harder to find someone who know the level and the song and it seems that even the song is custom, i found `Credits: Logo made by Stormboy99 and Monsterliam393! Enviroment made by Stormboy99 and Monsterliam393! **Music made by IChaosClay!**` this [*here*](http://lbp2.me/v/qnsm3x8/comments?p=1&l=12)

Comment: Voting to leave open as per http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7570/are-trivial-questions-allowed-on-the-site

Comment: I have tried most resources;iChaosClay's SoundCloud,Youtube,I've messages monsterliam393 and he said that he's unsure.Stormboy99 was a waste of time because he's not online.iChaosClay,i don't know about him. I've been looking for these songs for for over 2 years now.

Comment: lbp.me/v/qnsm3x8